# General solution of differential equation with tan

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to learn this type of question but this one is hardest one that I tried.

Find the general solution of the following differential equation:

$$y'' + y = \tan(t)$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you try? Can you update your question with the solution of the homogeneous equation? What do you know about finding solutions to second order ODE?

Comment: This is one of the few examples where the right side of the equation is not in "undetermined-coefficients" form that still allows to calculate all integrals. So it is an often used example, you should be able to find previous questions on it, like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936588/differential-equation, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3872563/find-the-general-solution, related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2769930/failure-to-correctly-apply-the-method-of-variation-of-parameters, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255228/how-to-solve-this

Answer (score 1):

Multiply with the cosine and add a cancelling zero
$$
[\cos(x)y''(x)-\sin(x)y'(x)]+[\sin(x)y'(x)+\cos(x)y(x)]=\sin(x)
$$
which can be integrated in all terms
$$
\cos(x)y'(x)+\sin(x)y(x)=-\cos(x)+C
$$
This linear DE now has integrating factor $\cos(x)^{-2}$, resulting in
$$
\frac{y(x)}{\cos(x)}=C\tan(x)+D-\int\frac{dx}{\cos x}.
$$
Now you can apply the "trick" $\frac1{\cos x}=\frac{\cos x}{1-\sin^2(x)}=\frac{u'(x)}{1-u(x)^2}$ or something different.